# Why can I bypass a "function takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)" error with assignment?

Tags: python, twitter, twython

I am trying to use Twython to work with the Twitter API in python, and I am observing some behavior that seems odd to me.

If I run the following code...

```
from twython import Twython
from random import randint

twitter = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET) # In the actual code, I obviously assign these, but I can't disclose them here, so the code won't work...

user_id = randint(1,250000000)
twitter_user = twitter.lookup_user(user_id)
```

I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "Twitter_API_Extraction.py", line 76, in <module>
twitter_user = twitter.lookup_user(user_id) # returns a list of dictionaries with all the users requested
TypeError: lookup_user() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

The Twython docs indicate I only need to pass the user id or the screen name (https://twython.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html). Some googling suggested that this error usually mean I need to pass *self* as the first parameter, but I didn't quite get why.

However, if I use the following assignment instead...

```
twitter_user = twitter.lookup_user(user_id = randint(1,250000000))
```

Everything comes up roses. I can't figure out why this is, and it is a problem later in the code when I am trying to access followers using the same lookup_user function.

Any clarification on what is triggering this error and how I am bypassing it via assignment in the function call would be most appreciated!

Comment: you need to give it a key/value pair `user_id = user_id` would work fine ...

Comment: The keyword argument error messages can be pretty confusing. Wait until you see `TypeError: f() takes at least 1 argument (1 given)`.

Comment: That is extremely helpful! Later on I use the call twitter.lookup_user(follower_id = follower_id), and it doesn't work, but... using twitter.lookup_user(user_id = follower_id) works fine. Is that related to the keyword argument error? It baffles me because I am passing the same id in either case. I can't see why it matters which variable I assign it to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [API documentation](https://twython.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#twython.Twython.lookup_user):

```
lookup_user(**params)
```

> Returns fully-hydrated user objects for up to 100 users per request, as specified by comma-separated values **passed to the user_id and/or screen_name parameters.**

The `**` syntax ([documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments)) means you need to provide *named* arguments (i.e. `f(a=b)`), in this case `user_id` and/or `screen_name`

In your first attempt you're trying to pass a *positional* argument (i.e. `f(a)`), which the function is not set up for.

Answer (score 2):

The API states that `lookup_user` takes keyword arguments only. Keyword arguments take the form `keyword=value`, which is what you are doing with `lookup_user(user_id=randint(1,...))`. It means you cannot pass positional arguments, which is what you are doing with `lookup_user(userid)`.